# pyspark RDD word calculate

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nltk, rdd

I have a dataframe with text and category. I want to count the words which are common in these categories. I am using nltk to remove the stop words and tokenize however not able to include the category in the process. Below is my sample code of the problem.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row
import nltk
spark_conf = SparkConf()\
        .setAppName("test")
sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate(spark_conf) 

def wordTokenize(x):
    words = [word for line in x for word in line.split()]
    return words

def rmstop(x):
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stop_words=set(stopwords.words('english'))
    word = [w for w in x if not w in stop_words]
    return word

# in actual problem I have a file which I am reading as a dataframe
# so creating a dataframe first 

df = [('Happy','I am so happy today'),
     ('Happy', 'its my birthday'),
     ('Happy', 'lets have fun'),
    ('Sad', 'I am going to die today'),
    ('Neutral','I am going to office today'),('Neutral','This is my house')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(df)
rdd_data = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(Category=x[0], text=x[1]))
df_data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_data)


#convert to rdd for nltk process
df_data_rdd = df_data.select('text').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)

#make it lower and sentence tokenize
df_data_rdd1 = df_data_rdd.map(lambda x : x.lower())\
.map(lambda x: nltk.sent_tokenize(x))

#word tokenize
data_rdd1_words   = df_data_rdd1.map(wordTokenize)

#stop word and distinct
data_rdd1_words_clean = data_rdd1_words.map(rmstop)\
.flatMap(lambda x: x)\
.distinct()

data_rdd1_words_clean.collect()
```

output : ['today', 'birthday', 'lets', 'die', 'house', 'happy', 'fun', 'going', 'office']

I want to count word(after the preprocessing) frequencies with respect to categories. For example: "today" : 3 as it is present in all three categories.

Comment: Can you post the current dataframe and the expected output you required?

Comment: Hi, I have included a sample data frame. I need to count how many word are present in all three category, how many are in two category and how many are in one. My actual dataset i have more categories.

Answer (score 0):

Here, extractphraseRDD is an RDD that contains your phrases. So the below code will count the number of words and display them in ascending order.

```
freqDistRDD = extractphraseRDD.flatMap(lambda x : nltk.FreqDist(x).most_common()).map(lambda x: x).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x+y).sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending = False)
```